# Multiple threads reading from same file/odd behavior

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm writing a program that needs to read lines from a very large file (400K+ lines) and send the data in each line on to a web service.  I decided to try threading and am seeing some behavior I did not expect, it appears like my BufferedReader starts reusing lines it's already given me when I call readline() on it.

My program is made up of two classes. A "Main" class that kicks off the threads and holds a static reference to the BufferedReader and has a static sychronized "readNextLine()" method that the threads can use to basically call readLine() on the BufferedReder. And the "Runnable" class that calls readNextLine() and makes a webservice call with the data from each readNextLine() call.  I made the BufferedReader and readNextLine() static just because that's the only way I could think of for the threads to share the reader aside from passing an instance of my main class into the threads, I wasn't sure which was better.

After about 5 minutes, I start seeing errors in my web service saying that it's processing a line it's already processed.  I'm able to verify lines are indeed being sent multiple times, minutes apart.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why the BufferedReader seems to be giving the threads lines it already read?  I was under the impression readline() was sequential and all I needed to do was make sure the calls to readline() were synchronized.

I'll show some of the Main class code below.  The runnable is essentially a while loop that calls readNextLine() and processes each line until there are no more lines left.

Main class:

```
 //showing reader and thread creation
 inputStream = sftp.get(path to file);
 reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

 ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);
        Collection<Future> futures = new ArrayList<Future>();
        for(int i=0;i<threads;i++){
        MyRunnable runnable = new   MyRunnable(i);
            futures.add(executor.submit(runnable));
        }
        LOGGER.debug("futures.get()");
        for(Future f:futures){
            f.get();  //use to wait until all threads are done 
        }

public synchronized static String readNextLine(){
    String results = null;
    try{
        if(reader!=null){
         results = reader.readLine();
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        LOGGER.error("Error reading from file");
    }

    return results;
}
```

Comment: I think you need to use `RandomAccessFile` and have each thread read from a different offset, though I'd use a single thread to read chunks of the file and for each chunk read, split off multiple threads to contact your webservice with parts of the chunk.

Comment: Actually I just stumbled on this, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousFileChannel.html I think it might do what you're trying to do if Java 7 is an option.

Answer (score 0):

I'm testing what you said, but I found you get an error logic in your readNextLine() method, how can reader.readLine() be invoked as the results is null and the if condition is it is not null?

Now I finished my demo, and it seems it works well, the following is the demo, no re-read line happened:

```
 static BufferedReader reader;

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"));
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    List<Future> results = new ArrayList<Future>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        results.add(service.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = readNextLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println(line);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
                }
            }
        }));
    }
}

public synchronized static String readNextLine() throws IOException {
    return reader.readLine();
}
```